# How to set shipping price to 0 when a specific field of product is enabled or has specific value

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce 7. I need to set the shipping price to zero when a field of product is enabled/checked (for example free ship field).

I know I should use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) and **Collecting shipping rates for an order** event is suitable for my job, but I really don't know how to set up a condition to check if my field is enabled or has a specific value.

I can set the free ship field widget as check box with enable/disable or select box with 2 value, whichever fits my needs. But my problem is how to set the condition according the value of product field.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

How about this: In shipping calculation rule see if can get the following conditions.

1. Use execute php code, check in the php if can use $commerce_order
2. If can then loop through all product line items in the order load them check the field value.
3. On basis of condition return True so implement the action or false to not.

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: what action I select in operation ? and which data selector?

Comment: I think php code in not suitable idea, maybe left it for last method.

Comment: you can start modifying any example shipping rule, so it will have shipping action by default and  you will be simply turning it on or of using php code in condition of rule, but yeah keeping it as last option will be best.

Comment: can you do it and export you rules?

Comment: when a cart will have a product with some shipping cost and another product with no shipping cost, what will be the shipping rule behaviour according to you?

Comment: The shipping cost of no shipping set to 0 and total will be equal  shipping cost of products that have shipping cost

Comment: @zhilevan I would'n be able to create the rule, as might take more time than I expect, but few pointers I found in between https://drupal.org/node/1409774

Comment: I try this but cant  load product
ym is something like dsm();
<?php 

$order=commerce_order_load($commerce_line_item->order_id);
$products=array();
foreach($order->commerce_line_items['und'][0] as  $line){
$products[]=$line;
}

foreach($prodcuts as $p_id){
$product = commerce_product_load($p_id);
ym($p_id);
}
ym($product);

?>